# Using instanceof to check and modify input

Tags: php, class, instanceof

I am using `instanceof` to check class instances and want to modify input data if class already has instance with same data. below example demonstrates my problem in detail where i have two unique array inputs and third one is duplicate array of second where `instanceof` supposed to work and modify input.

```
/**
 * Foo Class
 */
class Foo {
  public $bar = array();
  public function __construct() {}

  public function add( $bar ) {
    if ( $bar['ID'] instanceof Baz ) { // inctanceof not working as i am expecting. supposed to modify duplicate occurrence 

      //if bar['ID'] is already instance of Baz then we are trying to modify bar ID before pass it so Baz.
      $bar['ID'] = $bar['ID'] . rand();
      $this->bar[ $bar['ID'] ] = new Baz( $bar );
    }
    else {
      $this->bar[ $bar['ID'] ] = new Baz( $bar );
    }
  }
}
```

Class Baz

```
/**
 * Class Baz
 */
class Baz {
  public $ID;
  public function __construct( $bar ) {
    $this->ID = $bar['ID'];
  }
}
```

Instance

```
$foo = new Foo();

$bar = array( 'ID'  => 'bar1' );
$foo->add( $bar );

$bar2 = array( 'ID'  => 'bar2' );
$foo->add( $bar2 );

$bar3 = array( 'ID'  => 'bar2' ); //duplicate ID
$foo->add( $bar3 );
```

Print

```
print_r( $foo );
```

Output

```
Foo Object
(
    [bar] => Array
        (
            [bar1] => Baz Object
                (
                    [ID] => bar1
                )

            [bar2] => Baz Object
                (
                    [ID] => bar2
                )

        )

)
```

Expected Output

```
Foo Object
(
    [bar] => Array
        (
            [bar1] => Baz Object
                (
                    [ID] => bar1
                )

            [bar2] => Baz Object
                (
                    [ID] => bar2
                )
            [bar2{random number}] => Baz Object
                (
                    [ID] => bar2{random number}
                )

        )

)
```

what i am doing wrong in here? kindly guide me and alternate solution is also applicable.

Comment: what version of php do you have ?

Comment: i am trying this code on `PHP 7.1.10`

Comment: try `instanceof Baz::class`

Comment: @AlexanderMatrosov its giving syntacx eror `syntax error, unexpected 'class'`

Comment: A you absolutely positive it php7?

Comment: Yes, that's the exact version mentioned above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Foo class should look like:

```
class Foo {
  public $bar = array();
  public function __construct() {}

  public function add( $bar ) {
    if (isset($this->bar[ $bar['ID'] ]) && $this->bar[ $bar['ID'] ] instanceof Baz ) { // inctanceof not working as i am expecting. supposed to modify duplicate occurrence 

      //if bar['ID'] is already instance of Baz then we are trying to modify bar ID before pass it so Baz.
      $bar['ID'] = $bar['ID'] . rand();
      $this->bar[$bar['ID']]= new Baz( $bar );
    }
    else {
      $this->bar[ $bar['ID'] ] = new Baz( $bar );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: checking from class object in your solution works however i am getting Notice `Undefined Index error` for `bar1` and `bar2`. can we overcome this issue?

Comment: Use `array_key_exists()` instead of `isset()`

Comment: Thank you @Alexander, it works :) @Philipp, yes i am using `array_key_exists`